# Insert text into textarea and help text when mouseover buttons with jQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a buttons who insert different text into the textarea, now I also want different help text then mouseover the buttons, but I cant get it to work

Tip code I try to combine with the fiddle, but i cant get it to work together

```
<button id="button" onmouseover="mOver1(this)" onmouseout="mOut1(this)">Insert1 asdad</button>
<button id="button" onmouseover="mOver2(this)" onmouseout="mOut2(this)">Insert2</button>

<script>
    function mOver1(obj) {
        obj.innerHTML = "<div id='help_container1'><p id='help_text'>Help Text1</p></div>"
    }

    function mOut1(obj) {
        obj.innerHTML = "<button id='button' onmouseover='mOver1(this)' onmouseout='mOut1(this)'>Insert1</button>"
    }




 function mOver2(obj) {
        obj.innerHTML = "<div id='help_container2'><p id='help_text'>Help<br>Text2</p></div>"
    }

    function mOut2(obj) {
        obj.innerHTML = "<button id='button' onmouseover='mOver2(this)' onmouseout='mOut2(this)'>Insert2</button>"
    }
</script>
```

Fiddle to insert text into textaarea when click button
          http://jsfiddle.net/rmDzu/19

Fiddle to get help text when mouseover buttons
          http://jsfiddle.net/fTpwF

Anyone can help me to combine this fiddles into 1? It dont need to be this code in the fiddles at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean precisely, but... Check it:

```
$("#button").on({
    'mouseenter': function() {

        // make function for button

        // make function for textarea

    },
    'mouseleave': function()

        // make function for button

        // make function for textarea
    },
    'click': function() {

        // etc....
    }


});
```

-

Here is fiddle with your example:

http://jsfiddle.net/rmDzu/23/

Comment: No, I dont mean like that :) I should try to be more clear

The meaning is to have both functions in same time in these 2 fiddles, insert text into textare and hint text when mouseover the button!

http://jsfiddle.net/fTpwF/

http://jsfiddle.net/rmDzu/19/

Comment: jQuery or only JavaScript?

Comment: check update above. And never use the same name of ID in document

Comment: Its closer, but I want it to insert the text into textarea if you click the button, not only mouseover! Sorry if Im not clear enough

Comment: just add: 'click': function() {//make your function}. Check it above - Jsfiddle

Comment: Good, one thing is missing now, in my fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/rmDzu/19/) it will insert text into the position you are and in your version it insert in the last place all the time.  It that possible to fix in your fiddle?

Comment: Perfect solution  Filip

Comment: I tried but Im not aloud to do it yet, need 15 reputation. Sorry! I will try came back here when Im reached that!